# django-rest calculate different apps score using single method

Tags: python, django, rest

I am developing a django rest framework based api which keeps track of different apps score for different users. Now the problem is how to calculate different apps score using single method as different app have different score calculation equations.

```
class App(models.Model):
    """
    """

    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    description = models.TextField()
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(AppGroup)
    score_cal_equation = models.TextField() # To do : validate score calculation formula

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.name)
```

Now each user ll play an app and i have to calculate his score according to score_cal_equation....
for that i have taken variables like ....

```
class DecimalVariable(models.Model):
    """
    """

    app = models.ForeignKey(App, related_name="decimal_variables")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    var_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=APP_VARIABLE_CHOICES)
    is_required = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    default = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=18, decimal_places=6)
    max_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=6)
    min_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=6)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    score_dependency = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=SCORE_DEPENDENCY_CHOICES)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"Decimal: %d - %s" % (self.id, self.name)
```

same as above i have taken TextVariable,BooleanVariable so on....
every time i need to check if i have to  calculate score using DecimalVariable or TextVariable and then i ll calculate the score.

is there any better way to do it...?

Comment: Your question is a little vague. Try to be as specific as possible and support your question by providing code snippets where they can help us understand the problem so it's easier to help you.

Comment: like @TimCastelijns said you need a bit more detail

Comment: @TimCastelijns i added a bit more info...may be helpful to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar to this. If `score_cal_equation` does indeed need to allow arbitrary user input, you're going to have to write an expression parser, which you really want to avoid.

In my case, I chose to use Javascript as my expression language. That allowed me to use a Javascript parsing library to handle the expression parsing and calculation. When I needed to add variables, I just prepended `var foo = whatever;` to the expression and then let the Javascript evaluator do its thing.

My recommendation is this: If you need to allow arbitrary expressions (and without knowing more about what you are doing, I have to assume that you do), you're going to need an expression language. Try to use an existing one rather than inventing your own.